Conditionally wrap group of components in div in vue
I have a ref variable with the following structure
[ { "row": 1, "column": 1 }, { "row": 1, "column": 2 }, { "row": 1, "column": 3 }, { "row": 1, "column": 4 }, { "row": 1, "column": 5 }, { "row": 1, "column": 6 }, { "row": 2, "column": 1 }, { "row": 2, "column": 2 }, { "row": 2, "column": 3 }, { "row": 2, "column": 4 }, { "row": 2, "column": 5 }, { "row": 2, "column": 6 }, { "row": 3, "column": 1 }, { "row": 3, "column": 2 }, { "row": 3, "column": 3 }, { "row": 3, "column": 4 }, { "row": 3, "column": 5 }, { "row": 3, "column": 6 }, { "row": 4, "column": 1 }, { "row": 4, "column": 2 }, { "row": 4, "column": 3 }, { "row": 4, "column": 4 }, { "row": 4, "column": 5 }, { "row": 4, "column": 6 } ]

Then I want to iterate over this array to show a component and each different row should be wrapped with
<div class="row">  </div>

This is how I currently loop over the component
<Box v-for="(cell, index) in grid" :key="index"></Box>


What is the question? How to achieve this? It's straightforward to map the array to 2-dimensional array that could be accessed like arr[rowIndex][colIndex]. This is not specific to Vue. Then it can be iterated with nested v-fors

It becomes vue specific when I want to iterate exactly that array. Otherwise I can simply extract the highest row and column and do something like this
<div class="row" v-for="n in rows">
  <Box v-for="n in columns"></Box>
</div>


You can group the rows:
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const grid = [ { "row": 1, "column": 1 }, { "row": 1, "column": 2 }, { "row": 1, "column": 3 }, { "row": 1, "column": 4 }, { "row": 1, "column": 5 }, { "row": 1, "column": 6 }, { "row": 2, "column": 1 }, { "row": 2, "column": 2 }, { "row": 2, "column": 3 }, { "row": 2, "column": 4 }, { "row": 2, "column": 5 }, { "row": 2, "column": 6 }, { "row": 3, "column": 1 }, { "row": 3, "column": 2 }, { "row": 3, "column": 3 }, { "row": 3, "column": 4 }, { "row": 3, "column": 5 }, { "row": 3, "column": 6 }, { "row": 4, "column": 1 }, { "row": 4, "column": 2 }, { "row": 4, "column": 3 }, { "row": 4, "column": 4 }, { "row": 4, "column": 5 }, { "row": 4, "column": 6 } ]

const msg = ref('Hello World!')
</script>

<template>
  <div class="row" v-for="(rows, index) in Object.groupBy(grid, c => c.row)" :key="index">
    <div v-for="(cell,index) in rows" :key="index">{{ cell }}</div>
  </div>
</template>


If you are ok with functional components you could make a generic grouping control, moreover you could group directly virtual nodes, not data. A simple grouping control (grouping data):
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND

This is actually what I wanted to achieve but I was thinking in other direction. Thank you.

@LubomirBorisov i've added another approach to the problem, actually i use it in my projects, maybe that's what you wanted to achieve initially

That seems a bit more complicated on first look. My initial idea was to iterate over 1 dimensional array and somehow put the items between the div based on if row changes. For that I needed to check the previous iteration row value but thats something I guess its not optimal for vue.

@LubomirBorisov the problem Vue doesn't operate with HTML, it operates with VDOM, so it cannot for example add <div class="row"> and later add </div> ‍♂️

True. Coming from jQuery is a little bit strange I guess.
